# NASM x86_64 assembly in 32-bit mode: Why does this instruction produce RIP-Relative Addressing code?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, relative-addressing

```
[bits 32]
    global _start

    section .data
    str_hello       db  "HelloWorld", 0xa
    str_hello_length    db      $-str_hello

    section .text

    _start:

        mov ebx, 1              ; stdout file descriptor
        mov ecx, str_hello      ; pointer to string of characters that will be displayed        
        mov edx, [str_hello_length] ; count outputs Relative addressing
        mov eax, 4              ; sys_write
        int 0x80                ; linux kernel system call

        mov ebx, 0  ; exit status zero
        mov eax, 1  ; sys_exit
        int 0x80    ; linux kernel system call
```

The fundamental thing here is that I need to have the length of the hello string to pass to linux's sys_write system call. Now, I'm well aware that I can just use EQU and it'll work fine, but I'm really trying to understand what's going on here.

So, basically when I use EQU it loads the value and that's fine.

```
str_hello_length equ $-str_hello
...
...
mov edx, str_hello_length
```

However, if I use this line with DB

```
str_hello_length db $-str_hello
...
...
mov edx, [str_hello_length]     ; of course, without the brackets it'll load the address, which I don't want. I want the value stored at that address
```

instead of loading the value at that address like I expect it to, the assembler outputs RIP-Relative Addressing, as shown in the gdb debugger and I'm simply just wondering why.

```
mov    0x6000e5(%rip),%edx        # 0xa001a5
```

Now, I've tried using the eax register instead(and then moving eax to edx), but then I get a different problem. I end up getting a segmentation fault as noted in gdb:

```
movabs 0x4b8c289006000e5,%eax
```

so apparently, different registers produce different code. I guess I need to truncate the upper 32-bits somehow , but I don't know how to do that.

Though did kind of found a 'solution' and it goes like this:
load eax with str_hello_length's address and then load the contents of address that eax points to and everything is hunky dory.

```
mov eax, str_hello_length       
mov edx, [eax]  ; count


; gdb disassembly
mov    $0x6000e5,%eax
mov    (%rax),%edx
```

apparently trying to indirectly load a value from a mem address produces different code? I don't really know.

I just need help in understanding the syntax and operations of these instructions, so I can better understand why how to load effective addresses. Yeah, I guess I could've just switched to EQU and be on my merry way, but I really feel I can't go on until I understand what's going on with the DB declaration and loading from it's address.

Comment: This is not 32 bit mode. The registers `rip` and `rax` do not exist in 32 bit mode. So the problem is that you believe you are generating code for 32 bit, where in reality you have 64 bit code. That said, producing `rip` relative memory addresses is the default in x86_64, even if you don't explicitly state `rip` in the square brackets.

Comment: maybe it's the way I assemble and link. Cause I have: nasm -g -f elf64 $< for assembling and ld -o $(PROJECT_NAME) $(OBJ) for linking. If I change the format to elf32 I get an error:         ld: i386 architecture of input file `main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Comment: Use `gcc -m32` for linking, or the appropriate ld flag (`-m elf_i386`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is it isn't. x86-64 doesn't have RIP-relative addressing in 32-bit emulation mode (this should be obvious because RIP doesn't exist in 32-bit). What's happening is that nasm is compiling you some lovely 32-bit opcodes that you're trying to run as 64-bit. GDB is disassembling your 32-bit opcodes as 64-bit, and telling you that in 64-bit, those bytes mean a RIP-relative mov. 64-bit and 32-bit opcodes on the x86-64 overlap a lot to make use of common decoding logic in the silicon, and you're getting confused because the code that GDB is disassembling looks similar to the 32-bit code you wrote, but in reality you're just throwing garbage bytes at the processor.

This isn't anything to do with nasm. You're using the wrong architecture for the process you're in. Either use 32-bit nasm in a 32-bit process or compile your assembly code for [BITS 64].

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what the issue was! Changed [bits 32] to [bit 64] and did "mov edx, [str_hello_length]" and it loads from the address just fine! So it seems I have a lack of understanding in 32-bit and 64-bit programs, I guess.

Comment: It's not obvious, as RIP may not exist but EIP does.

Comment: @mid although EIP exists in 32-bit mode, it isn't accessible as directly as RIP in RIP-relative addressing. The most direct way you can implement PIE in 32-bit mode is by fetching the return address from stack after doing a `call`.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking the assembler to target 32-bit mode (with `bits 32`), but you're putting that 32-bit machine code into a 64-bit object file and then looking at what happens when you disassemble it as x86-64 machine code.

So you're seeing the differences between instruction encoding in x86-32 and x86-64.  i.e. **This is what happens when you decode 32-bit machine code as 64-bit**.

---

> `mov    0x6000e5(%rip),%edx        # 0xa001a5`

The key one in this case being that 32-bit x86 has two redundant ways to encode a 32-bit absolute address (with no registers): with or without a SIB byte.  32-bit mode doesn't have RIP-relative (or EIP-relative) addressing.

**x86-64 repurposed the shorter (`ModR/M + disp32`) form as the RIP-relative addressing mode**, while 32-bit absolute addressing is still available with the longer `ModR/M + SIB + disp32` encoding.  (With a SIB byte that encodes no base register and no index register, of course.  Fun fact: the scale field is unused in this case, but AMD64 chose not to do anything with those bits).

[rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base) details the "escape codes" in ModRM encoding that let it encode special cases like SIB-present, or no-base-reg.

Note that the decoded offset from RIP is actually the absolute static address where your data is placed (in 64-bit code), `0x6000e5`.

The comment is the disassembler showing you the effective absolute address; RIP-relative addressing counts from the byte after the instruction, i.e. the start of the next instruction.

---

> `movabs 0x4b8c289006000e5,%eax`

When the destination register is EAX, your assembler (in 32-bit mode) chooses the shorter `mov` encoding that loads `eax` from a 32-bit absolute address with no ModR/M byte, just `A1 disp32`.  [Intel's manual calls this a `moffs`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOV) (memory offset) instead of an effective address.

In x86-64 mode, that opcode takes a 64-bit absolute address.  (And is unique in being able to load/store from a 64-bit absolute (not RIP-relative) address without getting the address into a register first).  Thus, decoding consumes part of the next instruction as part of the 64-bit address, and that's where some of those high bytes in the address come from.  The `0x6000e5` in the low 32 bits is correct, and is how it would decode as 32-bit machine code.

---

> Changed `[bits 32]` to `[bit 64]`

See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).

Better to build a 32-bit executable if you aren't going to use native 64-bit system calls.  Use `nasm -felf32`, and link with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static`.

Comment: And BTW, you can use gdb's `set disassembly-flavor intel` to get Intel-syntax disassembly from `disas`, and from the disassembly window in `layout reg` mode.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the offset of `str_hello_length` is greater than 32 bits.  IA-32 doesn't support displacements of greater than 32 bits.  The way around that is to use RIP-relative addressing, under the (often correct) assumption that the distance between the RIP and the address you're trying to reach fits in 32 bits.  In this case, the base is `RIP` and the index is the instruction length, so if the instruction already has a base or an index, RIP-Relative can't be used.

Let's examine your various attempts:

```
str_hello_length equ $-str_hello
...
...
mov edx, str_hello_length
```

There's no memory access here, only a simply move with an immediate, so there's no addressing at all.

Next:

```
mov eax, str_hello_length       
mov edx, [eax]  ; count
```

Now the first instruction is a move with an immediate, which is still not a memory access.  The second instruction has a memory access, but it uses `eax` as a base, and there's no displacement.  RIP-relative is only relevant when there's a displacement, so there's no RIP-relative here.

Finally:

```
str_hello_length db $-str_hello
...
...
mov edx, [str_hello_length]     ; of course, without the brackets it'll load the address, which I don't want. I want the value stored at that address
```

Here you're using `str_hello_length` as your displacement.  As I explained above, this will result in RIP-Relative addressing.

Comment: oops, forgot to mention that I'm using AMD64 processor, though I'm not sure if that makes a difference. Thanks for the response! I'll look into it.

Comment: No, without `default rel`, `mov edx, [str_hello_length]` assembled in x86-64 mode would still use 32-bit absolute addressing.